# Apache Camel 3.X migration - ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.camel.impl.BreakpointSupport

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

When Migrating app from 2.X to 3.X, Build is successful but the tests fail with ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.camel.impl.BreakpointSupport

````
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/camel/impl/BreakpointSupport
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredClasses0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredClasses(Class.java:1867)
    at java.lang.Class$2.run(Class.java:1504)
    at java.lang.Class$2.run(Class.java:1499)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.getClasses(Class.java:1498)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassInfoMap.registerClass(ClassInfoMap.java:43)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassInfoMap.<init>(ClassInfoMap.java:29)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassInfoMap.<init>(ClassInfoMap.java:21)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:369)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:271)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:241)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:167)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$DefaultTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:663)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:260)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:198)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1295)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1273)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1128)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.camel.impl.BreakpointSupport
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 35 more```
````

```
pom.xml
${camel.version} --> 3.5.0 (tried 3.1.0 to 3.5.0)
${testng.version} --> 6.14.3
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-support</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-base</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>${testng.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
```

Class: BreakpointSupport is not used in the App, it's mostly a reference from one of the camel modules, and in the latest version of camel, BreakpointSupport is moved to org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor but it's still trying to fetch from the old location.

Comment: So did you read the migration guide? With JDK 11 a lot of things have changes.

Comment: @Namphibian I did, gone through https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/camel-3-migration-guide.html. I am still on Java 8 and as the migration document said they are still going to support Java 8 for earlier versions, I have also tested with 3.1.0, 3.2.0 and found no difference in the issue

Comment: According to https://camel.apache.org/blog/2020/03/LTS-Release-Schedule/ Camel has stopped supporting Java8 from 3.5.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue!

camel-testng was deprecated and camel encourages to use junit.
Moving to Junit5 solved the issue.